# JBPM6 install Issue - Jboss server and eclipse not opening

Tags: java, eclipse, jbpm, business-process-management, java-home

I am new to BPM and I am trying to learn jBPM6. I downloaded it and followed the steps that are provided in the document. I was trying to demo using `ant install.demo`. It worked up until I installed jbpm modular, but I got the following error: `No virtual machine found`. I have setup JAVA_HOME and ANT_HOME as well as the path system variable.

`Path : %JAVA_HOME%\bin;%ANT_HOME%\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\HP SimplePass\x64;`

`JAVA_HOME : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09`

`ANT_HOME : C:\ant`

`JBOSS_HOME : C:\jbpm-installer\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final`

`BUILD FAILED
C:\jbpm-installer\build.xml:508: JBoss application server did not start within 5 minutes`

**Note : i using windows8 - 64 bit.**

[image: Eclipse error]

Answer (score 0):

Regarding  the issue :BUILD FAILED C:\jbpm-installer\build.xml:508: JBoss application server did not start within 5 minutes

1. Check the jboss serverlog for issues.
2. One thing I got  was that, the jbpm 6 default installation tries to download a sample jbpm application project which is hosted in github. If we have no access to gihub it would the server startup would wait and would fail.
3. You can also increase the timeout ( But for sure if there is no other problem jboss boots up faster than the 5 mins limit ) in the build.xml goto target   and change the attribute maxwait in the  waitfor  tag.

For an assurance, I could get the jbpm environment up with the install.demo in windows 8 64 bit machine, the only problem was the connectivity with github. And the only difereence was I was using Java 1.6

Comment: Sure , i will change the maxwait and check it. I have this problem in 6.0.1. But i tried 6.0 its good and running properly.